# DropDownList GridView Row wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a `GridView` which reads from a `SQLDataSource`. The data source has a select parameter that pulls from a `CheckBox`. When checked outdated records are shown.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="showHidden" 
    ControlID="showHiddenEntries" 
    DbType="Boolean" 
    DefaultValue="0" 
    PropertyName="Checked" />
```

I am playing with an idea to save space in a `GridView` on a narrow page and have replaced the standard controls with a `DropDownList`. In the DropDownLists `onSelectedIndexChanged` I set...

```
DropDownList controlList = (DropDownList)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)controlList.NamingContainer;
int RowIndex = row.RowIndex;
string rowValue = gV.DataKeys[RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Then I have a switch statement for values of the `DropDownList`.

Running my select query with hidden entries shown produces the ID's

```
650, 663, 675, 679, 648, 660, 680, 668, 657, 649
```

Entries 650 and 675 are "hidden". With the `showHiddenEntries` `CheckBox` checked the `GridView` displays the IDs I listed. When I select something from the `DropDownList` and loop through gV's data keys I see

```
663, 679, 648, 660, 680, 668, 657, 649, 645, 652
```

The `RowIndex` is right, but the `rowValue` is wrong. I checked with another project where I did something similar and it looks identical to me and functions perfectly. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Thanks!

Toni W.

Edit: I just realized I worded that a little poorly. The `RowIndex` is correct, but the entire row is wrong, not just the `rowValue`. If I have `showHiddenEntries` checked, in my GridView row 0 is `10, "Jane", "Doe", hidden` and row 1 is `15, "Misc", "Person", shown` and I select fromthe DropDownList in row 0 `RowIndex` evaluates to 0 and the data is `15, "Misc", "Person", shown`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all the values are there, just not in the expected order. Typically this happens when you have sorting enabled. Try using the `DisplayIndex` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is it. The values where hidden = 1 are just not in `gV`'s `DataKeys`, the other x numbers are there and in the correct order.

Comment: @ToniW: I'm a little confused? Can you clarify?

Comment: I edited the original a little bit to include an example of what is happening. The ORDER BY is based on a datetime which does not change. If I have 100 rows and set my gridview to show them all they are returned in the right order and displayed in my GridView with the hidden values where they belong. If I activate a rows DropDownList and get the GridView using the code in the original post then loop through its DataKeys it shows 98 entries, excluding the ones where hidden = 1